# Deep clone an object that contains both an Immutable.js object and a vanilla JS object

Tags: javascript, lodash, immutable.js, draftjs

In my application, I have an object which contains both an Immutable.js object and vanilla JS objects. I would like to deep copy that object. With Lodash's cloneDeep function, I get a warning that says: `iterable.length has been deprecated, use iterable.size or iterable.count().`.

Is there a way to clone the entire object?

The object that I want to deep clone looks like this:

```
obj: {
  immutableJSObj: EditorState, // this is the one that can't be copied with Lodash
  vanillaJSObj: {
    a: { c: ... },
    b: { d: ... }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution. I knew that `Immutable.fromJS` deep clones an Immutable.js object. I was able to use the same function to the object that contained both Immutable and VanillaJS objects.

Example:

```
const clonedObj = Immutable.fromJS(sentences).toJS()
```

Comment: Note that `toJS` will convert the nested immutable object back to a non-immutable object too.

Comment: @dube I thought that would happen too. But when I tested it, the Immutable.js object remained the same. I think that's because when you use ```fromJS```, Immutable.js object gets wrapped again. So when it's unwrapped, the object inside remains the same. Here is a ```console.log``` after I cloned the object: https://imgur.com/RekXOqq . But thanks for your comment.

Comment: fromJS does not wrap already immutable objects. You would have to add more code to see what's going on, but your explanation can't be it.

Comment: @dube Probably you are right. I'm just guessing about what might have happened. I only use Immutable.js with Draft.js so I don't know much about it. But the function above, somehow, solved my issue. It would be great if you know a more reliable way.